# VBA in Excel - If statement Counter wont work

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, counter

I have been trying to get this VBA script to work to automate a task, but I cannot get it to work.

Basically, I have a big task list in excel with multiple columns and over 1000 Rows. It contains the task, who it is assigned to, and if it is open or closed.

In column H is who it assigned to and column N is whether the task is opened or closed.

I am trying to search by last name and if it is OPEN to add one to the counter. The end goal is to get a total count of how many open tasks a person has. Also, some of the cells in column N (task status) has extra text like comments, etc. I am sure that a InStr Function to search for the one word within the Cell would work better, but I cannot figure it out...

here is my code

```
Sub statuscount()

Dim tasksheet As Worksheet
Dim simons_count As Integer

Set tasksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tasks")

lr = tasksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 5 to lr
    If tasksheet.Cells(x, 8) = "Simons" And tasksheet.Cells(x, 14) = "OPEN" Then
       simons_count = simons_count + 1
End If

Next x

tasksheet.Range("$O$5").Value = simons_count

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Change `Simons_count As Integer` to  `Simons_count As Double` and `$O$5` to `O5`.

Comment: Couple of thoughts: A) You dont really need a macro for this, consider using the COUNTIFS function. B) You could have some trailing or leading spaces in your cells that are making the Boolean statement fail try something like Trim(tasksheet.cells(x, 8)) = "Simons", C) This is a side note, in VBA it is not important but always make sure you are initializing your coutner to 0.

Comment: Completely do not need VBA for this.  VBA is not an "automated" process because you have to run the macro each time.  Formula are automated and the solution to this is to use them.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am using a VBA script because I need to do more with it... To pull other information to get a bunch of different counts. I also export an excel sheet from a database making it hard to just have the formulas in the sheet. Also, when I save a sheet with a macro in it,when i reopen it, the macro no longer works... since Marcos are not enabled on my computer. I am new to VBA but I do have some basic experience in other languages. I have a lot of data in rows, and I need to have different "counters" for multiple instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using If/And gets tricky in VBA, you're better off nesting two if statements:

```
For x = 5 to lr
    If tasksheet.Cells(x, 8) = "Simons" Then
        If InStr(tasksheet.Cells(x, 14).Value, "OPEN") > 0 Then
            simons_count = simons_count + 1
        End If
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: I added the InStr function to the top one as well (since it is a full name, but using last name due to duplicate first names), and that worked... I used a small sample to get a simple solution, but what if I need it to check between 4 other people? I am assuming it would be a ElseIf statement, but since it is nested, where would I put it? So lets say, the 4 other people are: Randle, Jacobs, Carter, Ngyen. How would i get it to look at the row and add it to their respective counter?

Comment: A couple of ways I could think to do this easily; 1. Program an Inputbox to ask for which name you want to search for so then every time you run the code you enter which name you want to count. or 2. Put all of the names in an array and have it loop through each name in the array.

Comment: The Array sounds like a FANTASIC idea! I didnt even think about doing that. Once i got it to work, I have been trying to think of a way to condense some of the code. The sheet has about 60 co-workers, and I need counts (per person) of: # total tasks, # of Open tasks, # of Closed tasks, # of Moderate level tasks, and # of low level tasks... after getting all those counted I need it to print each of the totals for each person... I was doing it by hand and going crazy. It is my nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general function. Insert a module and past the below code in it. Than you can use the function just like any other Excel built-in function

```
Function LastNamecounter(lastName As String, status As String) As Long
    LastNamecounter = 0
    Dim tasksheet As Worksheet
    Set tasksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tasks")
    lr = tasksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 5 To lr
        If InStr(tasksheet.Cells(i, 8).Value, lastName) <> 0 And InStr(tasksheet.Cells(i, 14).Value, status) <> 0 Then
           LastNamecounter = LastNamecounter + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```